# ARC reference counting dealloc, and release

Tags: objective-c, ios, memory-management, automatic-ref-counting

I am getting a bit confused. I am creating an app with storyboard, and running it on iPad 1. the application uses a lot of memory, so reached the 120mb, crashes. accordingly to what I have understood to remove this problem you need to release, dealloc... the point is that with ARC this should be automatic. In fact if I add for e.g.: [label1 release]; it gives me an error. But this ARC automatic release and dealloc does not seem to work! Is this because there are different ways to release with ARC??

[image]

Comment: You may just be loading too much stuff.  Memory management can't help you with that.  Are you showing lots of images or video?

Comment: yes, images, but it's part of the app!!

Comment: How many are you loading at once and how big are they?  (Number of pixels not file size)  For the most part you should only have what is on the screen in memory.  Load on demand.  Not all at once.

Comment: Well I would need to know more about what exactly your app is doing to be able to answer that.

Comment: my initial view includes 6 photos, and I went to check the pixel density of one and it was in fact 1400*1200 so over the display capabilities.

Comment: Size them to exactly what you need.  If they are filling the whole screen then only load one at a time, as needed.  If you have all six showing at the same time then size the images down to exactly the size that they are being shown on the screen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to manually retain/release/autorelease with ARC. However if you have active references to a lot of unused objects they will still remain in memory. Profile your app with Instruments and it will show you how many objects you're creating of each class and how much memory they're consuming.

With ARC you still need to think about memory usage you just don't need to worry as much about memory leaks.

```
NSObject *bigMemObj = [[BigMemClass alloc] init];
//This creates the object in memory. In both arc and manual counting the retain count is 1

//Do stuff

//Prior to ARC you would have had to call [bigMemObj release]; before setting the variable to nil
bigMemObj = nil
//With ARC you don't have to do anything. The compiler inserts the release at compile time
```

Also read the documentation on declaring iVars __strong vs __weak.

Without looking at your code it's hard to identify what is consuming all the memory but hopefully that should help you determine where to start looking.

Comment: I can show you the code but I don't know which part because it is long

Comment: but I don't understand. what do you mean by the code above? If I created many labels/UIImageViews... in an NSMutablearray using alloc?

Comment: i have added instruments test: it says it uses only 2mb though (even if it showd no free memory left). at the end it crashed

Comment: Unused objects could be anything that you created and no longer need but have not "nilled" out. How did you get the 120MB number originally mentioned in your question? If you're crashing with only 2MB of memory allocated then your memory footprint isn't your issue.

Comment: Yes but if I see the gray bar (phisical memory used) it is about 120 with 3mb of free physical memory. There it crashes (for example when I import an image from the library, or change view). The memory free keeps decresing

Answer (score 0):

You should implement `@autoreleasePool{}` inside each method.  In essence, each method will look like the following:

```
-(void)methodName{
@autoreleasePool{
//do method stuff
}
}
```

This will ensure that, upon exiting the autoreleasePool, memory is properly released.

Comment: what should I add to //do method stuff?

Comment: lol anything you want your method to do.  Really, all you're doing is creating a separate autoreleasePool inside every method.  Experiment with it, and see what gets released and when.  I didn't even find out about this until I built (what amounted to) an infinite loop.  By using autoreleasePool, I was able to keep looping, allocating and releasing instance variables, almost indefinitely, until the array I was filling just got too big.  If not looping, you should just be able to set the pointer to nil (as cesarislaw mentioned).  If you are, put the [self doLoop]; outside the autoreleasePool.

Comment: Ok, so I added the above code to all of my codes. Everything still works but resulting to instruments it uses the same memory. Do i need to add a drain or something? (considering I am using ARC)

Comment: Are you setting your pointers to nil before exiting the autoreleasePool?

Comment: cesarislaw shows how to do it in the preceding answer.  myPointer = nil;

Answer (score 0):

I can't vote this back up, otherwise I would. I think Alessandro is asking about ARC vs using release and dealloc, not about what he's loading!

So, Alessandro, your understanding is correct that with ARC you don't release or dealloc. Therefore, those won't work if you're using ARC. Also, there is no alternative to release/dealloc, since ARC doesn't use it.

My suggestion would be to look at what you're using in the app that is taking up all this memory. Do you have a large number of pictures, for example, that are very large? Keep any graphics as small as possible, matching the resolution of the iPad. Especially the iPad 1, which doesn't have the "retina display".

You can use Autorelease pools in ARC. Here is some documentation on when to use them:
[NSAutoreleasePool Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSAutoreleasePool_Class/Reference/Reference.html)
[Advanced Memory Management Programming Guide: About Memory Management](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/MemoryMgmt.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000011i)